# how to find people via Twitter API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

I'm developing a network that people can add friends to and I want to give them an option to fine their friends via Twitter.

I'm trying to find that feature in the Twitter API.

How can this be done?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Find users in your network based on followers in twitter? Or find twitter users based on data in your network?

Comment: find twitter users based on username account...

Comment: Based on twitter username? Or usernames on your network? What happens if the user's using a different username on twitter?

Answer (score 0):

here you can find the API for what you're asking:

http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/friends/ids

as you can see, you have to make an HTTP GET request using this URL:

http://api.twitter.com/version/friends/ids.format ("format" could be xml or json)

you must specify user_id and username to avoid ambiguities.